# django some translations are not updated

Tags: python, django, gettext

When I change some translations some are keeping the previous value not the new one.

First, I have this file

```
#: choices/__init__.py:14
msgid "Power on"
msgstr "Encendido"
```

Then, I changed for this

```
#: choices/__init__.py:14
msgid "Power on"
msgstr "Dispositivo Encendido"
```

I compile the messages, but the translation is not updated. But only happens with some translation not all. I am in development mode, I not behind ningx. Also I restart the runserver.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

That could be because of the app loading order. If an app, defined later in `INSTALLED_APPS` defines a different translation for the same literal.

Comment: I do not have another app overriding the translations, just in one app I define translation for that literal. But actually what solve the issue was adding `LOCALE_PATHS `. I do not why but this works.